# How to set the Playnomics IOS SDK to production mode?

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, ads, playnomics

How can you set the IOS playnomics SDK to production mode?

A long time ago, there was a setTestMode method, but it is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playnomics SDK doesn't have a setTestMode any more. To do validation for testing your integration you can enter in your device identifier into the "Test Devices" section of the dashboard.

By default this will fall into a "Test Device" segment thereby keeping your production data separated from your test data. If you would like to add your device to the production set of data you can add the segments you want your device to fall into in the same section on the dashboard.

Otherwise, any devices that are not added to test devices will show up in production.